# MacBook Pro reset password

Tags: mac, password

My Macbok Pro is wanting me to reset my password.  I know my password but I can't get past this screen because the touch mouse doesn't work in this reset mode.

Comment: Which password is it asking for specifically?

Comment: Is it a terminal environnement? If so, you might want to know that password characters aren't hidden with '•' as you type, and there is no feedback at all. Maybe you have an issue with the keyboard localization?

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to be the problem. Thanks though!

Comment: @Pixelwiz, it's asking for my Apple ID but that's not the problem. When it's in the reset mode my trackpad doesn't work and I can't seem to figure out the correct keys to use that will work in place of it.  I'd up, down, double click, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard navigation using Tab & Enter
**OR**
Connecting a cable/wireless mouse *that has been unified/set up*

One more thing, I think the title of the question is misleading. 
"Trackpad doesn't work in Reset mode" That should get more answers quickly!